# SQL Alchemy column_property to check whether value is in set

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a model using sql alchemy and a set:

```
NON_RE_RUNNABLE_PIPELINES = {'pipe2', 'pipe1'}
class PipelineStatus(Base):
    __tablename__ = "pipeline_status"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    pipeline = Column(String)
    re_runnable = column_property(pipeline not in NON_RE_RUNNABLE_PIPELINES)
```

My intention was that `re_runnable` field would be `True` if the `pipeline` field is contained in the set, `False` otherwise. But it's proving to be incredibly difficult to do it.

When I query the code above, I get `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '_deannotate'`

If I try to use `re_runnable = column_property(literal(pipeline not in NON_RE_RUNNABLE_PIPELINES))`  instead, it also doesn't work, as it will check whether the NAME of the field is in the set and this is not what I want.

It seems the python expression I put inside column_property is not really executed on raw values, but instead it's converted into an expression with existing columns, which makes it hard for me to use it with a native set.

How can I implement such logic in my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `re_runnable = column_property(pipeline.in_(NON_RE_RUNNABLE_PIPELINES))`. From the output it can be seen that the filter works.

If you want the other way round you can do `re_runnable = column_property(pipeline.not_in(NON_RE_RUNNABLE_PIPELINES))`

Complete example as follows

```py
from uuid import uuid4
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, Column, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property, declarative_base, Session
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

Base = declarative_base()

NON_RE_RUNNABLE_PIPELINES = {"pipe2", "pipe1"}

class PipelineStatus(Base):
    __tablename__ = "pipeline_status"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    pipeline = Column(String)
    re_runnable = column_property(pipeline.in_(NON_RE_RUNNABLE_PIPELINES))

engine = create_engine('connection_string')

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(PipelineStatus(id=uuid4(), pipeline="pipe1"))
    session.add(PipelineStatus(id=uuid4(), pipeline="pipe2"))
    session.add(PipelineStatus(id=uuid4(), pipeline="pipe3"))
    session.add(PipelineStatus(id=uuid4(), pipeline="pipe4"))
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    for i in session.scalars(select(PipelineStatus).where(PipelineStatus.re_runnable.is_(True))):
        print(i.pipeline, i.re_runnable)
```

Output

```
pipe1 True
pipe2 True
```

Comment: that worked like a charm. I don't get why it was so hard to find... 
It seems this `in_` and `not_in` are column expressions, right? Thank you!

Comment: @mvallebr glad to have helped and yup they work on most column elements, https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.in_ in case you haven't seen that